# Define custom RMI port for HornetQ

Tags: configuration, rmi, firewall, hornetq

Running HornetQ 2.2.14 in standalone mode.
HornetQ is behind a firewall, thus requiring a static port.

How can one define this port?

[This page](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/UsingJBossBehindAFirewall?_sscc=t) shows how to define this port in JBoss, but has nothing about HornetQ standalone mode.
[This page](http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.2.14.Final/user-manual/en/html_single/) claims that the relevant configuration file (jboss-service.xml) is in a file called hornetq-service.sar, but it's not there...

So how is this done?